# Java itextpdf file output stream not actually closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

I'm trying to generate pdf files with a Java Spring Boot program using itextpdf 5.5.10. I managed to write desired content to pdf files, and I can open and view my generated files, but I cannot delete them. Every time I attempt to delete the generated files, I was prompted by Windows System that the file was in use by the Java SE platform. Yet about 10 to 15 minutes after the file is generated it can be deleted. The desired situation is that I can delete the file right after it is generated. It's really a weird situation to me, because I believe I've closed the document and the file output stream properly. Here's my code below:

I wrapped the methods provided by itextpdf in my own class `MyPdfWriter`:

```
public class MyPdfWriter {

    private Document document;
    private PdfWriter writer;

    private Font titleFont;
    private Font subtitleFont;
    private Font hFont; // heading font
    private Font pFont; // paragraph font
    private Font captionFont;
    private Font thFont;
    private Font tdFont;

    private static final float PAGE_MARGIN = 71f;

    ...

    public MyPdfWriter(String filename, String filepath) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        this.document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        this.document.setMargins(PAGE_MARGIN, PAGE_MARGIN, PAGE_MARGIN, PAGE_MARGIN);
        this.writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(this.document, new FileOutputStream(filepath + "/" + filename));
        // open document
        this.document.open();
        // set metadata
        this.document.addTitle(filename);
        this.document.addAuthor(ShiroUtils.getSysUser().getUserName());

        // set font style
        BaseFont bfChinese = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        this.titleFont = new Font(bfChinese, 16, Font.BOLD);
        this.pFont = new Font(bfChinese, 12, Font.NORMAL);
        ...
    }

    public void addTitle(String text) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph(text, this.titleFont);
        title.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        this.document.add(title);
    }

    public void addParagraph(String text) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text, this.pFont);
        this.document.add(paragraph);
    }

    public void addImage(String url) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        ...
    }

    ...

    /**
     * close writer
     */
    public void closeWriter() {
        this.document.close();
        this.writer.close();
        // I've tested this method with the following code:
        // this.document.isOpen(); // return false;
        // this.writer.isCloseStream(); // return true;
        // and nothing seems wrong...
    }

}
```

The class `MyPdfWriter` is instantiated and used in another class `ReportServiceImpl`:

```
@Service
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {

    ...

    @Override
    public int generateReport(Map<String, Object> data) {
        try {
            ...

            String filename = ...;
            String filepath = ...;

            // instantiate MyPdfWriter
            MyPdfWriter writer = new MyPdfWriter(filename, filepath);
            // write content to file
            writer.addTitle(...);
            writer.addParagraph(...);
            ...

            // close the pdf writer and file output stream
            writer.closeWriter();

        } catch (Exception e) {...}
    }

}
```

This problem has troubled me a whole day... I'm not sure where the problem lies, but I suspect it may be caused by the class `MyPdfWriter`. Can anyone familiar with Java and itextpdf tell what's going wrong with my code?

Comment: How about closing the output stream? by using try-with-resources: 
  try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)) {   this.writer = PdfWriter.getInstance...   }

Comment: @iLyas I've tried, but it worked the same as my code... The problem still exists.